# Extend visual appearance of Visual Studio 2013 solution explorer

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-extensions, visual-studio-sdk

The VS productivity power tools extend the solution explorer by eg showing squiggly lines below files with errors and some version control providers can show overlay icons. I know how editor extensions work which annotate the code editor, but I could not find the documentation for the solution explorer. Is there any documentation or sample for that?

Thanks in advance,
Christoph